# Pyspark tool in PyCharm tool

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed pyspark package in pycharma and now I am run pyspark code in pycharm. But I am not able to import all the the vaialbale classes/functions in the pyspark .sql module.

getting error for Sparksession module and hence not able to create dataframes.
Can you please suggest me what is wrong here.

Below is snippet for importing modules.

from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col
from pyspark.sql.Sparksessions

---

```
import pyspark.sql.SparkSession
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.sql.SparkSession'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`